# symfony2 : gearmanbundle with different environnement

Tags: symfony, gearman

i have a symfony2 app with gearmanbundle to handle gearman jobs. I have 2 same applications, one for dev, the other for demo. The 2 applications run the same workers, but with 2 differents path.
My first app run :

```
/usr/bin/php /home/app1/app/console gearman:worker:execute AcmeBundleWorkersTest --no-interaction
```

the second :

```
/usr/bin/php /home/app2/app/console gearman:worker:execute AcmeBundleWorkersTest --no-interaction
```

These workers are both handle by supervisord. My problem is my apps (which use differents databases) randomly call one of the 2 workers, so exception occurs because sometimes, one worker is called by the wrong application, and then can't retrieve database entity because they are in the other one.

Is it possible to tell my application which workers it can call ?

Comment: i found a temporary solution by setting up 2 differents gearman servers.

Comment: the solution above doesn't works :) any idea ?